# Socket.io connection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple **socket.io** connection on **localhost** but it's not working.

What I expect from my code is that when I enter command `node socket.js` it should console "**connected**" and at the same time on browser's console (I've already opened **index.html** page in a browser) I should see in console "**Connected...**" and "**Some thing to show**". But it's not working.

The server runs fine but I don't see data in both terminal and browser's console.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        console.log("Connected...");
        socket.on("message", function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

socket.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'}));
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/node_modules'));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log("connected");
   client.emit("message", "Some thing to show");
});
server.listen(8080);
```

My directory structure is like this:

htdocs/testproject/

..node_modules/

..index.html

..socket.js

EDIT: However, my code works when I add this in socket.js

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res,next) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Yup. No errors. Let me tell you something. It works when I add a get route in socket.js and write `res.sendFile('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/index.html');` in it. I want to do it without route.

Comment: Try changing your app.use to `app.use(express.static('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/'));` then, that should cause the server to serve the index.html properly at least. If that still doesn't work then something very strange is happening since your socket.io code works on my node.js server.

Comment: Well it worked when I changed the directory like yours. But it works only when I hit 127.0.0.1:8080 in browser. Why wouldn't it should any output to 127.0.0.1:8080/testproject/index.html ?

Comment: socket.io is designed to work in tandem with express. It'll only work properly if the page comes from a route the server recognizes as far as I can tell. Changing the app.use like that creates an automatic route starting there. Try out `127.0.0.1:8080/index.html`, it'll probably work.

Comment: Wait. Does it mean the things were working because 127.0.0.1:8080 was actually 127.0.0.1:8080/index.html (As we don't need to add the file name since it's INDEX) ? And 127.0.0.1:8080 won't work if I change the file name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to use `127.0.0.1:8080/newFileName.html` if you change index.html's name.

Comment: Yeah I got it. But I would also like to know why it didn't work when directory was '/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/node_modules'?

Comment: "localhost:8080/" was pointing to that folder. But, index.html was one level higher. If you take out node_modules, "localhost:8080/" points to the same folder as index.html. If it helps, it was trying to get the file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/node_modules/index.html" and failing silently since it didn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question related to this I would ask separately. Can I comment here when I need answer?

Comment: Make a new question if you have a new question, link it here if you want. Don't forget to see my below answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket.io library is designed to work in tandem with a node.js server, so the page the connection comes from needs to be recognizable to the server (through a route). Otherwise, how can it send anything back? If you change the express.static statement to be `app.use(express.static('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/'));`, you'll get an automatic route that will allow the library to do its thing properly. It's worth noting that you'll need to hit the base URL (that is, `localhost:8080/` or `localhost:8080/index.html`) when loading your page in the future if you use this. If you change the file name then use `localhost:8080/newfilename.html`.

In socket.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'}));
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/'));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log("connected");
   client.emit("message", "Some thing to show");
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: What if we don't write app.use(express.static()) thing? What is the importance of that?

Comment: Since you aren't using routes, "localhost:8080/" will default to wherever socket.js is located. You can also use that location in express.static by using the constant `__dirname`. If socket.js is located in "/opt/lampp/htdocs", an equivalent express.static would be `__dirname + '/testproject/'`.

Comment: Ok. Now what if I want to see response at some another file on another host say https://something.com/header.php (which contains the same code as index.html above), would that work?

Comment: If you're trying to access socket.io from another host that's an entirely different issue and something I'm unfortunately not versed in. Ask a new question for that and you'll get a new set of eyes on it.

Comment: Here's another question you may know about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575953/how-to-connect-to-a-socket-io-server-from-different-host

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things i can suggest you to try here.

First please check if **socket.io.js** is loaded properly.

Second, first start the server and then hit **http://localhost:8080** or **http://127.0.0.1:8080**

Also as far as i know you don't need to mention the host name on client side js when connecting. E.g.

instead of this

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
```

you can do this

```
 var socket = io.connect();
```

Comment: How to check socket.io.js is loaded? And second thing, I've written the path /socket.io/socket.io.js Is that right?

Comment: Further I saw Cannot GET / response when I hit that URL.

Comment: Open web page in chrome. Press F12, Chrome Debugger will open. Now if there is a error in Filepath it will log in Console with 404 status code. You can also check in Network tab if the file path is right.
Also don't forget there is a different socket.io.js for client side. Please do check if you're loading the same

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes. It is the one that worked after trying MANY other suggestions.

Comment: It's shows an error " io.connect is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

It is not working since you are opening the tab *before* you started your node application. It will request the socket.io.js file which can not be found and not will be reloaded. You need to start the server before you access the page and then it should work.

Comment: Can you debug socket.io in NodeJS, start it with this: `DEBUG=socket.io* node socket.js`

Comment: Change `var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');` to `var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:8080');` in your html.

Comment: There's no such issue. However it worked when I changed the directory mentioned in the comments of my question. But I see response only on browsing http://127.0.0.1:8080 and NOT on http://127.0.0.1:8080/testproject/index.html

Comment: Wanna answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575953/how-to-connect-to-a-socket-io-server-from-different-host

Answer (score 0):

You should use `options` when running the server; otherwise, it doesn't work properly.
Here is an example snippet from one of my projects.

```
  init: (httpServer) => {
    const options = {
      cors: true,
      origins: ["http://localhost:8080/"],
    };

    io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);
    return io;
  },
```

After that,

```
    const server = app.listen(8080);
    const io = init(server);

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("client connected");
    });

    io.on("disconnect", (socket) => {
      console.log(`client disconnected`);
    });
```