# How to connect to a socket.io server from different host?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a site say **mydomain/home.php**

Now I have set up a **NodeJs** server say at **23.23.234.22/home** (/home is a **get** route). I have written the code for **socket.io** server
and finally server is running.

Now I want to write client side code in **home.php** which would be similar to the code give below.

What I want is to send a request to **23.23.234.22/home** and I should see a socket response in **console** of browser when home.php is open. I want this to work every time I hit a request to it, not only when the server is connected.

I know, with this code things won't work. I don't know how
to do this. So what additional changes do I need?

socket.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'}));
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

 app.get('/home', function(req, res){
   //WRITE SOCKET SERVER CODE HERE?
 });

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/node_modules'));
app.use(express.static('/opt/lampp/htdocs/testproject/'));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log("connected");
   client.emit("message", "Some thing to show");
});
server.listen(8080);
```

home.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

//CHANGE FOLLOWING ADDRESS?
    var socket = io.connect('http://23.23.234.22/home');
    socket.on('connect', function(data) {
        console.log("Connected...");

    });

    socket.on("message", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im having similar issue any solution ?

Comment: I quit coding 2 years ago 

Comment: Yes, it really fixed the *problem* @vch 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in home.php

```
var socket = io.connect('http://23.23.234.22/home');
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://23.23.234.22:8080');
```